# Callback function result comes too late

Tags: node.js, express, pug

When I run this code, I have the problem that the page gets loaded too quickly and the server gets the information to display too late. On the main page nothing gets shown because it returns undefined but a few moments later, the variables cardTextBlack and cardTextWhite actually return the actual value they should display. How can I wait for those to return some actual data before the page gets fully loaded?

This is what I have in the modules

```
static findByColor(color, cb) {
    getCardsFromFile((cards) => {
        const cardList = cards.filter((c) => c.type === color);
        cb(cardList);
    });
}    

static async getRandomCard(cb) {
  const cardTextBlack = await this.findByColor('black', (cards) => {
     const randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
     return cards[randomCard].text;
  });
  const cardTextWhite = await this.findByColor('white', (cards) => {
     const randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
     return cards[randomCard].text;
  });
  cb(cardTextBlack, cardTextWhite);
```

}

In the controller I have this that gets passed:

```
exports.getMainPage = (req, res, next) => {
    Card.getRandomCard((blackText, whiteText) => {
        console.log(blackText, whiteText);
        res.render('index', {
            pageTitle: 'Index',
            blackText: blackText,
            whiteText: whiteText,
        });
    });
};
```

blackText and whiteText in the console.log in the controller are both undefined. Any solutions?

Comment: Where are you defining them?

Comment: They are defined in the getRandomCard function and then passed as onto the getMainPage

Comment: `blackText` and `whiteText` are not defined in `getRandomCard()`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not understanding. getRandomCard has cardTextBlack and cardTextWhite which are then passed into the callback function as arguments that should be executed in Card.getRandomCard callback. Correct?

Comment: I found out that the getRandomCard function gets executed too early. So the code is done executing, the variables get created and assigned to undefined. Although the variables themselves get the correct value afterwards, the page has already loaded and they never pass their value.